# How do I exclude a word from a regular expression search?

Tags: regex, qt, find

How I can create a regular expression for the following problem:

I have a string,
`name1=value1;name2=value2;.....;`

Somewhere, there exists a pair,
`"begin=10072011;"`
I need, with regular expressions, to parse from the string all name=value; pairs, where the value is a number. However, I want to ignore the name `begin`

Currently I have the following regexp:

```
([\\w]+)=([\\d]+);
```

Mine selects the `begin` name. How can I change it to not include `begin`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(?!begin)\b(\w+)=(\d+);`

This uses negative lookahead, so it will not match if the string starts with "begin".  The `\b` is necessary so that the regex does not just skip the "b" and match "egin=...".

Note that when describing a regex you should only using a single backslash for escapes, although for some languages you will need to use double backslashes to escape the backslash.

Comment: Thank you! Yes - double slash because of using c++ strings

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
\b(?!begin=)(\w+)=(\d+)\b
```

As aC++ string literal it would look like this:

```
"\\b(?!begin=)(\\w+)=(\\d+)\\b"
```

`\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html); you use it to make sure you're matching a whole word (as "word" is defined in the context of regexes; read that page carefully).  For example, without the first `\b` the regex would correctly fail to match

```
begin=1234   // OK
```

...but then it would skip ahead one position and match:

```
egin=1234    // oops!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `(?<=begin=)\d+(?=;)` will be a better choice.

If you keep all the information in XML format, the work will be much easier than now.

Comment: I would disagree with this answer in any case, but Qt's `QRegExp` flavor doesn't seem to support lookbehinds. ([ref](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qregexp.html#assertions))